# Problems accessing method parameter names of Groovy classes in Spring AOP 6.1+

Tags: spring, groovy, spring-aop, jep-118

Since 6.1
"Parameter Name Retention

LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer has been removed in 6.1."

even with -parameters in the java compiler, we are no longer able to do things like this

```
@CustomAnnotation(projectIdParameter = "projectId", userIdParameter = "#userEntity.id")
public ProjectEntity getProject(UserEntity userEntity, String projectId)
```

Because in the @Before passing in the JoinPoint, we used to be able to do

```
joinPoint.getSignature().getParameterNames()
```

However getParameterNames() is no longer available, and if you do cast getSignature to MethodSignature, getParameterNames returns null now.

What we are left to do is putting the functionality of the aspect into each method that was annotated before. We like using AOP for these security type issues, but not sure how to get it to work with the changes in Spring.

Is there anyway we can keep our AOP approach?

Comment: Does this help you: [parameter-name-retention](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-6.x#parameter-name-retention) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> even with -parameters in the java compiler, we are no longer able to do things like...

Then you are doing something wrong. This works just fine, both from Maven and when auto-importing the Maven project and running from IntelliJ IDEA:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-sample</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    <groovy.version>4.0.19</groovy.version>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
        <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>execute</goal>
              <goal>addSources</goal>
              <goal>addTestSources</goal>
              <goal>generateStubs</goal>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>generateTestStubs</goal>
              <goal>compileTests</goal>
              <goal>removeStubs</goal>
              <goal>removeTestStubs</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <parameters>true</parameters>
          <verbose>true</verbose>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-parameters</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>com.example.Application</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.groovy</groupId>
      <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
      <version>${groovy.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

```java
package com.example;

public @interface CustomAnnotation {
  String projectIdParameter();
  String userIdParameter();
}
```

```java
package com.example;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class SampleService {
  @CustomAnnotation(projectIdParameter = "projectId", userIdParameter = "#userEntity.id")
  public void doSomething(int foo, String bar, Object zot) {
    System.out.println("Doing something in service method");
  }
}
```

```java
package com.example

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service

@Service
class GroovyService {
  @CustomAnnotation(projectIdParameter = "projectId", userIdParameter = "#userEntity.id")
  void doSomething(int foo, String bar, Object zot) {
    System.out.println("Doing something in Groovy service method")
  }
}
```

```java
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args)) {
      applicationContext.getBean(SampleService.class).doSomething(11, "dummy", new Integer(42));
      applicationContext.getBean(GroovyService.class).doSomething(11, "dummy", new Integer(42));
    }
  }
}
```

```java
package com.example;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Arrays;

@Aspect
@Component
public class SampleAspect {
  @Before("@annotation(CustomAnnotation)")
  public void beforeServiceMethodExecution(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    System.out.println(joinPoint);
    System.out.println(
      Arrays.toString(
        ((MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature()).getParameterNames()
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Console log:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.3)

2024-03-09T14:53:30.327+01:00  INFO 14188 --- [           main] com.example.Application                  : Starting Application using Java 21 with PID 14188 (C:\Users\Alexander\Documents\java-src\SO_AJ_Spring61ParameterNames_78129715\target\classes started by Alexander in C:\Users\Alexander\Documents\java-src\SO_AJ_Spring61ParameterNames_78129715)
2024-03-09T14:53:30.329+01:00  INFO 14188 --- [           main] com.example.Application                  : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-03-09T14:53:31.201+01:00  INFO 14188 --- [           main] com.example.Application                  : Started Application in 1.193 seconds (process running for 1.734)
execution(void com.example.SampleService.doSomething(int,String,Object))
[foo, bar, zot]
Doing something in service method
execution(void com.example.GroovyService.doSomething(int,String,Object))
[foo, bar, zot]
Doing something in Groovy service method
```

Spring Boot 3.2.3, Spring 6.1.4, JDK 21, Groovy 4.0.19.

---

**Update:**

- My reproducer can be found in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/kriegaex/SO_AJ_Spring61ParameterNames_78129715). Branch `master` contains the mixed Java & Groovy solution shown here, branch `pure-groovy` the Groovy-only variant.
- For the problem that parameter retention in the byte code is not imported correctly into IntelliJ IDEA, I have just created issue [IDEA-348776](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-348776). But that is only an IDE problem, the Maven solution above still works for both mixed Java & Groovy and pure Groovy projects.

Comment: Thanks. We are using Groovy so not the maven Java plugin. And we do already have the <parameters>true… but still doesn’t work.

Comment: Why did you not mention that fact inb your question? There also is not corresponding tag? I guess, that is kind of essential. If it does not work, do not look at Spring but at your Groovy compiler options. I have just proven to you that it works in Spring, if the class files contain the necessary information.

Comment: I added a Groovy service and GMavenPlus to the mix, and it works flawlessly when running the application with Exec Maven, see my updated answer. What I did notice is that IntelliJ IDEA only finds the parameters when running the program after a Maven compile. But when recompiling in the IDE from scratch, it prints null for the parameter names. I am not so experience with Groovy, but probably the IDE compiler config somehow needs to be told to do the right thing. As an experienced Groovy user, probably you can find out how that is done. It does not seem to generate stubs.

Comment: Or maybe just use Groovy Eclipse Compiler instead of Groovyc via GMavenPlus, then you do not need stubs, as far as I remember. I always compile my Spock tests with GrEclipse. Only for this example I used GMavenPlus, because probably it is more popular. But I prefer GrEclipse.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but the issue is more Spring for us. I named all the @RequestParam("nameHere") to get passed the issue with -parameters. But in the case of SpEL and AOP that doesn't help. But you have <compilerArgs> <arg>-parameters</arg>          </compilerArgs> And that is different than what I have, so I will try what you have and see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: Nope, that is not part of the GMavenPlus plugin. And I can do mvn clean install and technically wouldn't need "nameHere" for RequestParam, but still doesn't resolve the AOP issue Where the arguments are not in the JoinPoint object. I think I am going to refactor the entire AOP/Custom Annotation approach. Either directly in the Service methods, or some other way to get the values into the Aspect/Advice method. Thank you for your recommendations and help.

Comment: The problem is sitting in front of the computer, sorry to say that. Please note the two different ways to specify the parameter name generation for Maven Compiler vs. GMaven+. Just to prove you wrong, I even refactored all my Java classes from the example in my answer into pure Groovy, and it still works in Maven. You do not need to refactor, you need to get your build configuration fixed. To stubbornly blame it on Spring does not touch on the root cause of your problem. I posted **proof** that it works the way I described, you only **claim** that it does not.

Comment: How about publishing a minimal reproducer for your problem on GitHub instead of making other people who want to help you chase their tails because of your incomplete information?

Comment: Please note the links to my GitHub repository and a newly created IntelliJ IDEA issue in the updated answer.

Comment: I am sorry I am making you upset, and you are being extremely helpful and I do appreciate it. I am adding the Maven compiler plugin to match your GitHub solution, and will let you know in a couple of minutes.

Comment: Perfect. Adding the Maven compiler plugin with GMaven+ Works. Thank you so much for your patience and help.

Comment: Actually, it didn't work all the way. But that is not about compile args, that seems to work, but this is now Spring AOP that is at issue, in that the getParametersNames() is no longer available in the Signature object. I will find a solution to that elsewhere, make that a separate post. But for this post regarding the change and need for -parameters, that is resolved. Thanks.

Comment: Again, you did not carefully study my sample code. Please use `((MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature()).getParameterNames()`. That is AspectJ API, not Spring API, and it has not changed, because AspectJ is not even part of Spriung but an independent project. Just use the right API.

Comment: I did try that before and it didn't work. It returns null. I completely understand what is under what project.

"However getParameterNames() is no longer available, and if you do cast getSignature to MethodSignature, getParameterNames returns null now."

Comment: I don't know why it works in your sample, but not in our application. I added the plugin to the pom file, I used the same code, but I am still getting null for parameter names

Comment: Also the implementation of MethodSignature (interface in AspectJ) is MethodInvocationJoinPoint which is in the package org.springframework.aop.aspectj;

So while the interface is in one project, the implementation is in Spring.

And now while stepping through Spring's code, now it is returning the argument names, whereas just 2 minutes before with the same code it wasn't. I literally changed nothing and now it works. Thanks.

Comment: In the 2 minutes, All I did was find the MethodInvocationJoinPoint, then in IJ did download sources so I could set a breakpoint in that class in getParameterNames() method on the first line. Ran the UI which I knew calls the @Before method and it started to return the parameter names after just stepping through the code.